# Not able to update value when i click button,Mutable state error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

issue-> so when i click on submit button the count value is not increased and also not the words are matched but when i click the counter button the value is increased

```
//main acitivity code

   class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WordGuessingGameTheme {
                 val count = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(0)
                }
                val scrambledword = remember {
                    mutableStateOf("ankit")
                }

                val userinput = remember {
                    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
                }
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                HomeScreen(count,scrambledword,userinput)
            }
        }
    }
}




//home screen code
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    count:MutableState<Int>,
    scrambledword:MutableState<String>,
    userinput:MutableState<TextFieldValue>
){
    var isSuccessful by remember {

        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.White),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,


    ){
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Text(text = scrambledword.value, fontSize = 12.sp)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            TextField(value = userinput.value, onValueChange ={newValue:TextFieldValue->
                userinput.value=newValue
                isSuccessful=false
            }
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
             CreateButton(name = "submit",
                 onClick ={
                     compare(userinput.value.text, scrambledword.value) {isSuccess->
                         isSuccessful=isSuccess
                         count.value++
                 }



                 }
             )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            if (isSuccessful==true){
                Text(text = "correct")
            }
            else{
                Text(text = "enter a word")
            }
            Button(onClick = { count.value=count.value+10}) {
                Text(text = "Counter")
                
            }
            Text(text = "aaaa")
           Text(text = count.value.toString())


        }

    }

}

const val comp="check"
fun compare(a: String, b: String, onMatch:(Boolean)->Unit){

    if (a.toString() == b.toString()) {
        Log.d(comp,"in a==b")
         onMatch(true)
    }else{
        Log.d(comp,"in a!=b")
        onMatch(false)
    }

}

@Composable
fun CreateButton(
    name:String,
    onClick:()-> Unit
){
    Button(onClick = {onClick},
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
//            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        Text(text = name, style = TextStyle(
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,

            )
        )
    }

}
```

I was expecting to match both the words and if i enter correct word that the text shows correct
other than it shows "enter a word"
but even if i write the correct word it do not changes anything.
tried on chatgpt and bard and bing chat also nothing helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 'CreateButton' composable you are passing the 'onClick' lambda.

This does not need to be enclosed in curly braces.

```
@Composable
fun CreateButton(
    name:String,
    onClick:()-> Unit
){
    Button(onClick = {onClick},
        modifier = Modifier
```

should read

```
@Composable
fun CreateButton(
    name:String,
    onClick:()-> Unit
){
    Button(onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier
```

Alternatively, you can keep the curly braces to make another lambda and call your original lambda using invoke()

```
@Composable
fun CreateButton(
    name:String,
    onClick:()-> Unit
){
    Button(onClick = {onClick.invoke()},
        modifier = Modifier
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mike_Hall for helping it works.
Could you plz explain what is going on when I enclose it in curly braces?

Comment: The Button composable's 'onClick' property is expecting to receive a lambda, in this case '() -> Unit'. When we pass the lambda, the code we want to run is enclosed in curly braces:
{ codeToRun() }
You passed this lambda to your CreateButton composable, which in turn passes it to the Button composable, but by enclosing it in curly braces again, you are effectively passing a lambda that just contains a lambda. That internal lambda will not run unless you specifically tell it to with .invoke()
Your 2 options, then, are either pass the lambda as it is, or pass a second lambda with .invoke()

Comment: The reason we can .invoke() it is that you may wish to 'add' to the lambda before passing it to the composable.

eg:

Button(onClick = {
Log.d("MyLogTag", "The button has been clicked!")
onClick.invoke()
},
  modifier = Modifier

Comment: Thank you so much again @MikeHall 